# Get timezone name in codeigniter

Tags: php, datetime, codeigniter, timezone

I use the date helper in CI to save the timezone of the user when he signup eg: UM45.

I want to set the timezone of each user based on that and display the date time correspondingly, using `date_default_timezone_set()`.

But that accepts only string.. How can I get the name of the timezone based on UM45?

Comment: The correct answer can be found here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212620/codeigniter-timezone-menu-and-date-default-timezone-set

Answer (score 1):

Seems it can be done via the [Language Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html):

```
$this->lang->load('date_lang');
$this->lang->line('UM45');
```

Comment: The value returned by `$this->lang->line($time_zone_code)` cannot be used directly on `date_default_timezone_set()`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I guess you'd have to create your own array or class that maps CodeIgniter timezones to timezone strings accepted by PHP.