# Codeigniter, timezone_menu and date_default_timezone_set

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone

I make use of Codeigniters `timezone_menu` which gives a [drop down box](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html) of time timezones and I am wondering how are we supposed to make use of these timezones with PHPs `date_default_timezone_set`?

An example of codeigniters timezone is `UP1`. However, you can't use that with PHPs `date_default_timezone_set` as the string it takes in should be something like `Europe/Berlin`

**The question is, is there a way to convert a codeigniter timezone string to a PHP one that can be accepted by the `date_default_timezone_set`?**

Comment: the question is why does codeigniter's date helper provide that set of values if they have no use in their intended context?

Comment: According to the doc, Codeigniter doesn't suggest to set the `date_default_timezone_set()`. And that is exactly my problem. I think its better to select between php's native date functions or Codeigniter. I'm taking my decision (while I had used Codeigniter's till now)

Answer (score 7):

The following works for me:

```
// Example - timezones is part of the date helper function
// You obviously wouldn't echo it out, you would pass it in to 
// set default timezone function in PHP based on the posted data from 
// the dropdown
echo timezone_by_offset(timezones('UM5')); // ouputs 'America/Porto_Acre' which is (-5)

// And the function
function timezone_by_offset($offset) {
    $offset = ($offset+1) * 60 * 60;
    $abbrarray = timezone_abbreviations_list();

    foreach ($abbrarray as $abbr) {
        foreach ($abbr as $city) {
            if ($city['offset'] == $offset) { 
                echo($city['timezone_id']);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    echo "UTC";
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**
The original function didn't exclude DST offsets. timezone_abbreviations_list() lists 2x for a timezone that has DST marked as true, for example Tasmania appears under +11 and +10. So if DST == TRUE, ignore it as part of the return listing.

```
//-- Function -------------------------------------------------------------------
function timezone_by_offset($offset) {
    $abbrarray = timezone_abbreviations_list();
    $offset = $offset * 60 * 60;

    foreach ($abbrarray as $abbr) {
        foreach ($abbr as $city) {
            if ($city['offset'] == $offset && $city['dst'] == FALSE) { 
                return $city['timezone_id'];                                
            }
        }
    }
    return 'UTC'; // any default value you wish
}
```

Some examples:

```
//-- Test Cases -------------------------------------------------------------------
echo timezone_by_offset(-12) . '<br/>';  
echo (date_default_timezone_set(timezone_by_offset(-12)) == TRUE ? 'Valid' : 'Not Valid'). '<br/>'; 
// Etc/GMT+12
// Valid 

echo timezone_by_offset(-10) . '<br/>';  
echo (date_default_timezone_set(timezone_by_offset(-10)) == TRUE ? 'Valid' : 'Not Valid'). '<br/>'; 
// America/Anchorage
// Valid

echo timezone_by_offset(-8) . '<br/>';  
echo (date_default_timezone_set(timezone_by_offset(-8)) == TRUE ? 'Valid' : 'Not Valid'). '<br/>'; 
// Etc/GMT+8
// Valid        

echo timezone_by_offset(6) . '<br/>';  
echo (date_default_timezone_set(timezone_by_offset(6)) == TRUE ? 'Valid' : 'Not Valid'). '<br/>'; 
// Asia/Aqtobe
// Valid        

echo timezone_by_offset(7) . '<br/>';  
echo (date_default_timezone_set(timezone_by_offset(7)) == TRUE ? 'Valid' : 'Not Valid'). '<br/>'; 
// Indian/Christmas
// Valid
```

Comment: Good function - it seems to work, why do you plus 1 to $offset by default at the beginning?

Comment: I should've mentioned, I was manually entering the day light difference. The +1 * 60^2 should be against the $city offset if DST = 1. I can rewrite the function as another answer if required.

Comment: @Chirs - I would be interested to see how you would handle the DST. Is it a manual thing where I would I have to pass the DST to the function or can it be worked out by the `timezone_abbreviations_list` somehow?

Comment: @Chris - that's brilliant. Thank you! I didn't know `timezone_abbreviations_list` stored it twice for timezones that have DST.

Comment: @Abs Not a problem, I hoped it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the UTC offset for one of the `U(M|P)x`-values by using `timezones()`.

```
$offset = timezones('UP1'); // don't know the exact format returned but should be something like 1 or '+01:00'
```

From this point on, I think the only way is some sort of custom mapping between the offset and the PHP timezone. You could use `Etc/GMT(+|-)x` timezones but the problem with those will be that they do not contain any DST-transition information.

The problem in general is, that the UTC-offsets actually map to a lot of different timezones, e.g. `UP1` (*(UTC + 1:00) Berlin, Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris, Rome*) maps to `Europe/Berlin`, `Europe/Brussels`, `Europe/Copenhagen`, `Europe/Madrid`, `Europe/Paris`, `Europe/Rome` but also to `Africa/Luanda` for example. The thing now gets arbitrarily complex due to the DST-transitions that may oder may not occur in some of these timezones.

If you don't need the DST-thing, a mapping between the return value of the `timezones()` function and the `Etc/GMT(+|-)x` timezones should be OK, otherwise you cannot use the Codeigniter timezone handling at all because the mapping is not unambiguous.

Comment: That is an excellent idea Stefan! It gives me an idea in turn. I think I can then make use of the `timezone_name_from_abbr`. It also has support for the DST! I think this then might be the correct use `timezone_name_from_abbr('', $offset * 3600, true)` - what do you think - it seems to work for me?

Comment: I didn't know the `timezone_name_from_abbr()` function until now, but that seems to be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter gives the timezone reference back, which can be used with timezones() to get the time diff and from their you can calculate the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value of the timezone offset in the gmt_to_local() function for example:

```
//set the time offset based on the users timezone settings
$timezone = 'UM7';

$offset = timezones($timezone);
$servertime = time();

$mytime = gmt_to_local($servertime,$offset);

$time = date("M d, Y h:i A", $mytime);

//example result
//Dec 22, 2011 04:18 PM
```