# how to convert PHP timezone string(e.g Europe/Berlin) to codeigniter timezone(e.g. UP1)

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, timezone

In a short if i have to ask this question is [just the vice verse of this link question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212620/codeigniter-timezone-menu-and-date-default-timezone-set) .

I am  using a javscript library  which automcatically detects the timezone and returns the time zone name in  PHP format i.e `'Europe/Berlin'` format.

But I make use of Codeigniters `timezone_menu` which gives a [drop down box](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html) of time timezones and I am wondering how can i convert this php time zone (i.e `'Europe/Berlin'` ) to  codeigniters timezone format i.e `UP1`.?

Comment: probably defining some arrays, and cross matching them

Comment: @Kyslik thanks for your suggestion, Kyslik  a  answers exists in stackoverflow just opposite of my question http://stackoverflow.com/a/5457291/2732367                     Hoping someone may help me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from [the CodeIgniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html) that they are treating time zones as fixed offsets.  Their convention is fairly straight forward:

- `UTC` to represent *exactly* UTC.

  or
- `U` to represent UTC
- `M` or `P` for Minus or Plus
- A number to describe the offset

  - A single digit for whole hour offsets
  - Two digits when there are half-hour offsets, but these are shifted funky (you would think +05:30 would be represented by `UP55`, but its actually `UP45`

So why did they do this?  Who knows.  It's not a standard thing, it's a CodeIgnitor special format.  Normally an offset is just represented like `+05:30` or `+0530`.

Using an offset to represent a whole time zone is out of sync with reality.  If it was that easy, then we wouldn't need the IANA time zones like `Europe/Berlin` in the first place.  You can see [in the time zone list here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) that `Europe/Berlin` alternates between +01:00 and +02:00.  Code Ignitor might say that it is `UP1`, but then that wouldn't ever take into account the daylight time offset.  (Daylight saving time is different all over the world, so you can't just augment this with a checkbox and expect to be reliable.)

So, if you must have CodeIgnitor's strange form of time zone representation, then take the base offset of the IANA zone and apply their funky formula (as dev-null-dweller showed [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18688803/634824)).  Just don't expect it to be accurate.

And if you're in zone with a :45 offset, then you're out of luck.  That would be `Pacific/Chatham` or `Asia/Kathmandu`.

You can read more in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timezone) under "Time Zone != Offset"

Just to add something actually constructive to to this answer, I recommend not using CodeIgnitor's time zones.  Just stick with the IANA zones [as provided for you by PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).  They are even kept up to date via [timezondb in the PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb).

Comment: ... especially the last paragraph

Comment: Use [`timezone_identifiers_list`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php) in PHP.  Or if you want something fancier but more user-friendly, try a map-based picker like [this one](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker).

Comment: @MattJohnson I have implemented this functionality as you suggested in your last para, and it works fine. I implemented  IANA zones as provided  by PHP for timezone values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know CI that much, but from quick look at the date helper documentation, it looks like  it can be created from offset:

```
$now = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
$offset = $tz->getOffset($now) / 3600;

$ci_tz = 'U';
if($offset) {
    if($offset < 0) {
        $ci_tz .= 'M';
        $offset = abs($offset);
    } else {
        $ci_tz .= 'P';
    }
    if(is_float($offset)) {
        $offset = $offset * 10 - 10;
    }
    $ci_tz .= (string)$offset;
} else {
    $ci_tz .= 'TC';
}
var_dump($ci_tz); // UM3 = UTC Minus 3 hours
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `but unfortunately it is not giving the correct answer..`  Eg, i kept "Asia/Kolkata" in your example instead of "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"     , but the output it is giving is `UP55` , which is wrong.  It should be `UP45` for  "Asia/Kolkata"  as shown in codeigniter timezone documentation page

Comment: Right, it was not so logical as it looked on first sight. Half hours are offseted by one hour in CI notation. Edited my answer with this correction.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like a good formula to convert offsets to CI's strange format.  But do realize that it is basing the offset on `$now`, which will mean different input at different times of the year due to daylight saving time.  See my answer for more detail.