# Codeigniter 3 - how to display date and times in user's time zone

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use codeigniters' timezone_menu().  I store a [timezone reference](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html#timezone-reference) in my db.

The timezone reference looks like UM12, UM11, UM10, UTC, UP1, UP2, etc, etc.

With [timezones()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html#timezones) I can get the hour difference from UTC.  What I want to do is set the user's time zone with date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); but that method doesn't accept the timezone references that CI uses.  How can I do it please?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there is a time_zone variable in the config/config.php

```
$timezone = session_value ?? dfault_value;
```

once a user login to your system assign the timevalue and refer that variable into the config or create a hook, i am sorry i am in little hurry i was searching something else but I think this will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter TimeZone functions uses a [custom naming](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html#timezone-reference) for its timezone: `UM12`, `UM11`, `UM10`, `UTC`, `UP1`...

These are not common and thus will only work for CodeIgniter's own TimeZone functions, wich are `timezone_menu()` and `timezones()`.

The PHP function [`date_default_timezone_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) expects an [proper TimeZone identifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) like `Europe/Paris`.

The best way would be to use something else to generate your list of TimeZone. But I understand your interest in using CI's internal lib than looking for yet another library to do this for you.

So I guess you need to search for a function which takes CI's TimeZone identifiers and outputs PHP's TimeZone identifiers. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212620/codeigniter-timezone-menu-and-date-default-timezone-set) seems to have what your are looking for.